# Implementing a Camel transform

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb, middleware

I have the following Camel route:

```
RequestToOrderTransform requestToOrderTransform =
    new RequestToOrderTransform();

from("ghttp:///processOrder")
    .transform(requestToOrderTransform)
    .bean(OrderProcessor.class)
    .to("direct:endOfRoute");
```

It uses Camel-GAE to receive an `HttpServletRequest` from a GAE servlet (`processOrder`), then transforms the request into an `Order` POJO, and finally processes that order (`OrderProcessor`).

I would like to write my own `org.apache.camel.Expression` (`requestToOrderTransform`) and so far I have the skeleton/framework:

```
public class RequestToOrderTransform implements Expression {
    @Override
    public <T> T evaluate(Exchange arg0, Class<T> arg1) {
        // ???

        return null;
    }
}
```

In here, somehow, I have to transform an `HttpServletRequest` (which I *believe* is what I get from the GAE servlet consumer) into my own `Order` POJO. But I'm not sure how to obtain the `HttpServletRequest` in the first place. Once I have the request I can extract out the necessary params and then instantiate my new order instance. But then I'm not sure what to do with the `Order` so that Camel knows to route it and not the original `HttpServletRequest`.

So I ask:

1. How do I obtain the instance of my `HttpServletRequest` (or whatever object I get from the GAE servlet endpoint)?
2. How do I set my newly instantiated `Order` instance so that Camel uses it as the unit to route (on to the `OrderProcessor` bean)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing an expression seems like a bad way to go, when all you really is implementing is a message translator. But any way, just grab the body as string an do whatever with it.

```
arg0.getIn().getBody(String.class)
```

I'm not sure what data you get from GAE in this case, but if it's structured (json,xml,flat files, csv), you might want to look at the [various data formats](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html) that does string to java object conversion for you.